# Eloquent Relationships Can't get Column result from Lookup

Tags: php, oop, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I just can't get my head around Relationships in Eloquent. Just when I think I've got it, I stumble.

Like here, I want to list out the `country` field for each `Headquarters_Pay_Data` item.

Models;

```
<?php

namespace Datamate;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Headquarters_Pay_Data extends Model
    {
        //
        protected $table = 'headquarters_pay_data';


        public function postcode()
        {
            return $this->hasOne('Datamate\Postcode_Quarter', 'postcode', 'Vendor ZIP');
        }

    }
```

And this one;

```
<?php

namespace Datamate;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use Datamate\Country;

    class Postcode_Quarter extends Model
    {

        public $table = '201502_postcode';

        protected $fillable = ['country'];

}
```

My controller;

```
public function index()
{
    //
    $headquarters_pay_data = Headquarters_Pay_Data::limit(12)->get();

    foreach ($headquarters_pay_data as $key => $value) {       

        //print $value->postcode->country; //this returns an error. Trying to get property of non-object
        print "<br><br>";
        print $value->getAttribute('Vendor ZIP');
        print "<br><br>";
        print $value->postcode; //this is JSON?! Why?
        print "<br><br>";

    }
```

Example print out of what looks like JSON even though I haven't asked for JSON;

```
RH108PJ

{"postcode":"RH108PJ","county":"E10000032","district":"","ward":"","health":"E18000008","gor":"J","parlc":"E14000652","locauth":"E07000226","wardcode":"E05007639","country":"E92000001","gor_new":"E12000008","pct":"E16000108"}
```

To clarify... How do I just print out the `country` for each payment?

Answer (score 1):

The `postcode` field, due to your eloquent relationship method, is an instance of another model (`Postcode_Quarter`) on the `Headquarters_Pay_Data` model. So `$value->postcode` returns that model (as a PHP object). Your turning that model to a string (by `print`ing it) makes it try to convert itself to the best possible format for use as a string, which is a JSON string.

However, you *can* access the properties of that model, and because you want the country you can do the following:

```
public function index()
{
    $headquarters_pay_data = Headquarters_Pay_Data::with('postcode')->limit(12)->get();

    foreach ($headquarters_pay_data as $key => $value) {       
        print $value->postcode->country; 

    }
}
```

You'll notice that in this example we also use `with()` in order to 'eager load' the `postcode` relationship. This, generally, makes your queries more efficient, especially in the case where you have a lot of the `Headquarters_Pay_Data` models, and not very many `Postcode_Quarter` models, but it is not required to have this work.

Please read the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading) for more information on eager loading.

Comment: Actually.. I discovered that my problem was because I had postcodes in my payments table that had no corresponding lookup value. I literally just discovered it. I should maybe start using TDD! However, this is a good suggestion as well.

Comment: @Shanoop no problem - the answer was sound, just needed a bit of explanation as to what was going on exactly. Seemed silly to add a separate answer with the same actual answer but just more description.